# Sending data with AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

Here's the code I use and it doesn't work when I try `echo $_POST['count'];` on 
`page.php`

```
<input type="submit" value="go" id="more">
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#more').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
        url: "page.php",
        data: {"count":3} //saving number 3
        });

  });
 });
</script>
```

In page.php.

```
  <?php echo $_POST['count'];?> //doesn't work.
```

Comment: Define `doesn't work`. What errors do you get? Check your JavaScript console. You likely need a `success` handler to do something with the results of the AJAX call - it won't magically show up somewhere on the page.

Comment: How much debugging have you performed? Have you debugged your Ajax call with Firebug, or a comparable tool, to see if your POST _is_ sending the data to the script?

Comment: `data: {count: <?php echo $number; ?>}`

Answer (score 1):

`$number` is undefined in your JavaScript.  When this happens, most if not all browsers don't post the data.  It is undefined because the variable doesn't exist in the JavaScript scope.  I think you meant to echo the PHP value.

Try this

```
<?php  session_start(); 
 $_SESSION['n'] = 3;  
 $number = $_SESSION['n'];?>

<input type="submit" value="go" id="more">
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#more').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
        url: "page.php",
        data: {"count":<?php echo($number);?>}
        });

  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: `$number` is assigned to a session variable `$_SESSION['n']` and is trying to access it via `$_POST['count']`, so I can't see how `$number` would show up in page.php. Therefore, an additional problem the OP may have is that `session_start();` is not in page.php

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I don't think so.  `$_SESSION['n'] is set the the constant "3".  He is trying to post that value back to the server via ajax.  He could have got rid of the session lines of code, and would have the exact same results.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking over everything again a few times, so I'd have to test everything out myself just to be sure. I'm not saying your answer is wrong ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  No worries :)  That is what makes this site great.  Multiple eyes!

Comment: Well, it's conclusive. HTML source revealed `data: {"count":3}` in using your answer and instructing OP to *"echo the PHP value"*.

Comment: Always good to test!  The OP did a rookie mistake, but then again, we've all been there.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question and it doesn't work. Please help

Comment: @sofa_surfa  What doesn't work?  Your `click` callback should be working okay.  Are you posting data?  Use Firebug or similar Chrome or IE tools to check.  Then in your server, add something like `var_dump($_POST);` to make sure it is getting the values.

Comment: I'm thinking OP wants to echo it on the same page and would need to add another function and a div to echo it inside of.

Comment: Why are you using Ajax then if you're wanting to echo in another page? @sofa_surfa

Comment: @Fred -ii-  Could you please show me how to add a div and a function to echo on the same page? Thanks

Comment: @sofa_surfa  Instead of `echo $_POST['count'];`, use `var_dump($_POST);` at the very top of your page.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax sends out a request from the client to a remote server, and then gets a response. Your page.php script needs to echo out some type of a response text, that you can then use on the Client side UI.  I think you might be trying to submit a form.  Which would look like this:

```
<?php  
session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION['n'])){ $number = $_SESSION['n']; }
else {$number = "<DEFAULT VALUE>";}
?>

<body>

<form name="formname" action="<?php echo "page.php?number=$number ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="go" id="more">
</form>

</body>
```

Then on page.php, you can get the number variable like this:
$number = $_POST['number'];

*Note: You can pass variables to a remote script using $.ajax().  That remote script would then take those variables, and issue back a response. Here is some documentation on using ajax with JQuery [Click here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

To echo a session variable on the same page, you can use a named hidden input and using the value from the `$number` variable; i.e.: `value="<?php echo $number;?>"`, then using a `<div>` as the element to show up inside of.

**page.php** would contain:

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['count'];
```

This is the code that you will load in your browser, and using jQuery:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?>

<?php 
 $_SESSION['n'] = 3;  
 $number = $_SESSION['n'];
?>

<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#submit-button').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'page.php',
        data: $("#theform").serialize(),
success: function(d){
   $(".result").html(d);
}
    });
  });
 });//end document ready
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="some_id">
<form id="theform">
 <div>  
   <input type="hidden" id="count" name="count" value="<?php echo $number;?>" />
 </div>

 <div>
   <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
 </div>
 </form>
</div>
   <div class="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to create formdata object and append input or some private data to it. After that send this object with xmlhttp object to server.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("count", 3);
var xmlhttp;
..................
xmlhttp.send(formdata);

$count = $_POST['count'];
```